# Is there some way to render BR tags with javascript's DOMParser?

Tags: javascript, domparser

The DOM that results from `DOMParser.parseFromString()` does not appear to be exactly the same as the DOM that is created by the browser (chrome) given the same string, in particular, concerning the rendering of `<BR>` tags.

If we create a `<DIV>` and then add some HTML to it and then examine its innerText, we find that the `<BR>` tag is ignored.

```
div=document.createElement("div")
div.innerHTML="test<br>test"
console.log(div.innerText) 
// prints -> "testtest"
```

However, if we inject this into the document rendered by the browser, we find that the `<BR>` tag is replaced by a newline.

```
document.body.appendChild(div)
console.log(div.innerText)  
// prints -> "test\ntest"
```

If we create a document using `DOMPaser.parseFromString()`, we find that `<BR>` is ignored the way it is by the `<DIV>` node before it is injected into the document.

```
p=new DOMParser()
doc=p.parseFromString("asdf<br>asdf", "text/html")
console.log(doc.body.innerText)
// prints -> "testtest"
// not -> "test\ntest"
```

Is there some way to parse an HTML string and have it render the `<BR>` tags the same way that the browser does with newlines?

Comment: `innerText` is non-standard anyway. Use `textContent` instead.

Comment: @Quentin Well exactly - it yields `testtest` as it should, whereas `innerText` does some shenanigans that convert `<br>` to newline but only when attached to the document...

Comment: It turns out, in my case, those 'shenanigans' are useful so I was wondering if there was some way to replicate those 'shenanigans' with DOMParser.parseFromString().

Comment: You might have to do some DOM manipulation then. For example, find all `<br>` tags and add a text node containing `\n` after each one.